# how database foreign keys cascade mysql

Tags: database

I created a set of tables in a database.A assigned relations with foreign key.
i am not getting cascading effect of data in mysql.

i created a table named ME and with MY_ID column name
I also created table named MY_Friends with MY_ID column name and foreing key with references to ME(MY_ID).

I am able to notice cascading effect in mysql

### Me

My_ID         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0

### My_Friends

My_ID               | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |

there are two columns description in two tables

Comment: please put the schema definition for the tables

Comment: sorry i am not able to edit .

Answer (score 1):

`FOREIGN KEY` and `CASCADE` will have no effect if the tables are `MyISAM`. Check if the tables are defined using the `InnoDB` engine. Give us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Me` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Friends` so we can verify if that's the problem.

Comment: how to change MyISAM to InnoDB

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Me ORDER BY My_ID;` then `ALTER TABLE Me ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: i tried that and change that to InnoDB but i am not able cascade

Comment: Without your actual schema, I don't think we can help you much further. We need to see the foreign key definitions. Try creating the FOREIGN KEY again after conversion to InnoDB, I believe that MyISAM might not even store the FK information at all.